# An Easy Mate In 1

Tags: chess

[image: 3N2R1/pp3p2/3K2p1/8/2pk4/3pp2p/3P1pB1/1Q4BR w - - 0 1]

As stated in the title, white must mate black in 1 move. But first you must solve the mystery behind this puzzle.

---

*This puzzle was created by Hieronymus Fischer (1843-1927).*

Comment: Why does the Rook at h1 has a dot on it? Unless it is relevant for the solution (looks like not given the nice answers and already one accepted) the it probably should not be there. My bet would be that "dotted rooks" can fly; so R*h4++

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires A dot in the lower right square is commonly used to indicate whose move it is.

Comment: isnt it checkmate if he moves B1 to B2?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea No, black can place a pawn between the queen and the king: `1. Qb2 c3`.

Comment: To clarify Sleafar's comment for those less versed in chess, black starts in ranks 7 and 8, meaning that the black pawns are moving "down" the board in this image.

Comment: I saw this puzzle in my chess club many years ago. It came with a claim that it was from the early days of chess, where the Bishops were actually *alfils*, which moved one or two squares and could jump over pieces. The solution was thus Bg1xe3#.

Comment: Are white's pawns moving towards the top or the bottom of the grid? I'm not familiar with whether white or black is traditionally at the top of a chessboard, and the answer to my question affects my attempts to solve the puzzle.

Comment: @Kevin The board is numbered. But even if it was missing or you suspected it was lying, you could look at some specific square to know which side started at the bottom. For example, the bottom right square, or the queen's starting square, indicates the side.

Comment: @Kevin White pawns are moving upwards, black pawns downwards.

Comment: @Reti43 Looking at the bottom right square is not sufficient to determine the direction each is moving.  If you rotate the board 180 degrees, the bottom right square will still be white but the directions are the opposite.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The mystery

> There are 9 pawns on the board (black supremacy propaganda?). If we remove any of them to make it legal, we can mate in 1.

The mate

> Remove a7, 1. Qb6#
>  Remove b7, 1. Nc6#
>  Remove c4, 1. Qb4#
>  Remove d3, 1. Qe4#
>  Remove e3, 1. Bxf2#
>  Remove f7, 1. Ne6#
>  Remove f2, 1. Bxe3#
>  Remove g6, 1. Rg4#
>  Remove h3, 1. Rh4#

Additional note

> We note the double pawns occur on the f file. A potential question could be whether we could remove any of the pawns and still have the board position reachable legally. The answer is that no pawn removal matters. For example, if we removed the a7 pawn, the pawn that is currently at f2 originally started at a7 and with sequential captures traversed a7, b6, c5, etc to reach f2. We can similarly show that for any other pawn from any file, the pawn at f2 could have started from that file and reached f2 legally.

Comment: I don't see how you get to "fix" the problem this way.  BaSzAt gives a perfectly good answer--this position isn't illegal in tandem chess.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I like BaSzAt's answer, too, but it seems the answer I went for is the intended solution to the puzzle, i.e., removing any of the 9 pawns results to a unique mate in 1. We should also note that while this position in bughouse is legal, it makes the implicit assumption that your ally is in a position to provide you with a piece you can checkmate with. And if clocks are involved, you also have the time luxury to wait on your turn until that happens. While these might be reasonable assumptions, they are assumptions nevertheless, which might taint the beauty of the solution.

Comment: Having said that, chess puzzle composers don't have to abide by any rules. You can have impossible compositions (board crammed with pieces), illegal solutions (promoting to an opponent's piece), solutions that require assumptions (en passant/castling are available) or cooked up solutions (helpmates). In most cases the point of such puzzles is homing in on such absurdities because there are no other viable solutions.

Comment: The promoting to an opponent's piece puzzle was legit--at the time the rules didn't specify that you could only promote to your own piece, nobody had considered that someone might want to promote to an enemy piece.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Hah! Nice one, I didn't know this.

Comment: @Reti43: When I've played bughouse with friends, we had a rule that a player could only use a piece that became available before the opponent's last move.  I don't know if that rule was commonplace, but it helped avoid problems of a player waiting around for a piece.

Comment: I looked at the OP and noticed the extra pawn. But I don't understand what gives you the right to "remove any of them". It simply looks to me like the board is set up in error and there is no solution. Or perhaps it is mate in 0 because black has cheated and has an invalid setup.

Comment: @Paul As I've mentioned in a comment above, not all chess puzzles are serious. I think you're approaching this a bit too literally. We're on Puzzle SE, it'd have been boring had the OP made an error than there being an unusual solution. I have as much right to remove a piece as black can have 9 pawns to begin with and this right is irrelevant to the nature of this puzzle.

Comment: @supercat In my experience the preferred approach was clocks but if they weren't available we used that rule of no piece you didn't already have.

Comment: You could spin it in such a way that black was caught cheating or having made a mistake setting up (which solves "the mystery") and as such was forced to remove one of the pawns, leading to the rest of Reti43's answer.

Answer (score 18):

A possible explanation to the mystery:

> This is [tandem chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bughouse_chess).

In which case:

> You might have a queen or a rook in your deck. Drop it on d5... quickly!

Comment: A knight on b5 or bishop on c5/e5 would also do the trick. So as long as your ally can force a minor/major piece capture before getting mated, you can play for the win. Cool thinking by the way.

Comment: A pawn at c3 also mates, I believe, which I think covers all the pieces.

Answer (score 8):

Alternate solution that does not notice or take care of the excess of black pawns

The mystery:

> The board is oriented opposite the usual direction: white started at the top and white pawns advance toward the bottom of the board.

The mate:

> Queen to a1 or b2. Black can't interpose the pawn because his pawns advance up the board.

Note:

> We have to assume that the black pawn at d3 got there by capturing something *after* the white pawn at d2 obtained that position. No explanation for the pure number of pawns that have not already queened.

Comment: The orientation of the board is well-defined because of the included labeling. White always starts in the 1st and 2nd row, black in the 7th and 8th row.

Comment: The rules of how things are "always" done are often ignored in puzzling.SE.

Comment: @Sleafar Yet a well defined rule of the amount and type of pieces on the board has been broken. Black always has no more than 8 pawns yet here we are with Black having 9.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate solution: The pawns are [Berolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berolina_chess) pawns (which move diagonally and capture straight ahead; thus, the pawns on d2 and d3 are threatening each other); and Black gave odds by replacing his queen with another pawn on d8.

This allows Qb2 (or Qa1) mate.